# Refused to apply style from auth/css when rendering

Tags: html, css, node.js, handlebars.js

**Problem:**

I quite confused to why my `render` is not loading my `css` and `images` from `uploads`.

When I **do not** try to log in, every page loads it's `images` and `css` applies it's styles..

But when I try to render my page like so:

```
if(!results.length){
  res.status(401).render('home/login', {
    message: 'The email or password is incorrect'
  });
}
```

I get this **error**:

[image]

I realized it says `...:3000/auth/css/..` - it's not suppose to load `auth`?

**This is my tree:**

```
Index.js
|
├───controllers
├───helpers
│
├───public
│   ├───css
│   ├───javascript
│   └───uploads
├───routes
│   └───home
└───views
    ├───home
    ├───layouts
    └───partials
        └───home
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();

// Public path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Parse URL encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//Parse JSON bodies as sent by API clients
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// View engine
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'home-index'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Routing
app.use('/', require('./routes/home/page_routes'));
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening');
  });
```

**views/layouts/home-index.handlebars**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{> home/home-nav}}

    {{{body}}}



  </body>
</html>
```

**routes/auth.js**

```
const { db } = require('./db');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var { promisify } = require('util');


// Login
exports.login = async function(req, res) {
    try {
      var {email, password} = req.body;
  
      if(!email || !password) {
        return res.status(400).render('home/login', {
          message: 'Please provide an email and password' ///////////////// This is the problem
        });
      }
  
      db.query('select * from users_website where email = ?', [email], async function(error, results){
        console.log(results)
  
        if(!results.length){
          res.status(401).render('home/login', {
            message: 'The email or password is incorrect' ///////////////// This is the problem
          });
        }
        else{
          var id = results[0].id;
          var token = jwt.sign({ id }, 'SuperSecretPassword9981998', {
            expiresIn: '90d'
          });
  
          console.log("The token is: " + token);
  
          var cookieOptions = {
            expires: new Date(
              Date.now() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
            ),
            httpOnly: true
          }
  
          res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
          res.status(200).redirect("/");
        }
      });
  
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

**routes/home/page_routes**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth_controller = require('../../controllers/auth');

// Home router
router.get('/', auth_controller.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.render('home/index');
});

// Login
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Question**

How do I get rid of the error - when trying to render the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that you are loading assets using *relative* URLs in your handlebars file, which means that the assets are loaded relative to the page's URL, which, in your case, is `:3000/auth`. To fix this, use an *absolute* URL instead.

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Notice the leading slash. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{> home/home-nav}}

    {{{body}}}



  </body>
</html>
```